# Slide fixed div up and off the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML `<div id="topDiv">` that is `position:fixed` to the top of the browser window.

If I run `$("#topDiv").slideUp();` the `<div>` disappears, but the contents of the `<div>` are hidden from the bottom up, meaning the contents remain completely static during the animation.

**Using jQuery, Is there a way to "hide" the `<div>` so that the entire thing appears to slide up and off the window, rather than be hidden?**

See the following snippet as an example of what I mean...

```js
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    $("#topDiv").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#topDiv {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#fa8072;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topDiv">This content will disappear when <a id="topA" href="#">this is clicked</a><br/>The text will disappear as the bottom edge of the box moves up.<br/>But the text itself will stay completely static while that happens.</div>
What I would like is for the contents of &lt;div id="topDiv"&gt; to slide up, giving the impression that it is leaving the screen, rather than being hidden.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use .animate() method, instead of .slideUp(). And do not use pixels, use percents.

```
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    $("#topDiv").animate({top: '-=100%'})
  });
});
```

And of course, instead of .slideDown(), you must use this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    $("#topDiv").animate({top: 0})
  });
});
```

But for best perfomance, I suggest you this solution, as `transform: translate` is hardware accelerated, so you will obtain most fluent animation:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    $("#topDiv").toggleClass('hide')
  });
});
```

```css
#topDiv {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#fa8072;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="topDiv">This content will disappear when <a id="topA" href="#">this is clicked</a><br/>The text will disappear as the bottom edge of the box moves up.<br/>But the text itself will stay completely static while that happens.</div>
What I would like is for the contents of &lt;div id="topDiv"&gt; to slide up, giving the impression that it is leaving the screen, rather than being hidden.
```

Comment: I like the idea, but `-=100%` appears to be the entire height of the window... not the height of the `#topDiv` box... so even giving a duration value of `10000` (i.e. 10 seconds) it's gone almost immediately

Comment: @freefaller Don't worry, it is really just 100% of topDiv height.

Comment: @freefaller Just use my recommended solution, from reasons I mentioned, and change speed in `transition` from 0.4s to value you need. There is no better solution.

Comment: I would avoid using statements like *there is no better solution*... you might think that is the case, but it isn't always so.  However, I do like the use of the `translateY` CSS

Comment: An improvement in my mind would be to not have a second class, but update the script using the technique from Savado... `$("#topDiv").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(-100%)' });` See, I think that's a better solution already

Comment: @freefaller But there is really no better solution for smooth animation. I just know what I am talking about. Unfortunately, nowadays, only few attributes are hardware accelerated. Fortunately, `transform: translate` is one ot them. You animation will be smooth best possible way, which .animate({top: 'x'}) just is't.

Comment: @freefaller Yes, you can use your idea with `.css()`, instead of `.toggleClass()`. But be aware you are doing it for expense of code readability and maintainability. In HTML, hold HTML. In CSS, hold CSS. An in JS code, have JS code, not CSS.

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for reassigning.

Answer (score 3):

The .animate() method can make it works

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```js
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    $("#topDiv").animate({top: "-200px"});
  });
});
```

```css
#topDiv {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#fa8072;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topDiv">This content will disappear when <a id="topA" href="#">this is clicked</a><br/>The text will disappear as the bottom edge of the box moves up.<br/>But the text itself will stay completely static while that happens.</div>
What I would like is for the contents of &lt;div id="topDiv"&gt; to slide up, giving the impression that it is leaving the screen, rather than being hidden.
```

Comment: It's a really good start, but it would better if it wasn't a fixed pixel height, and took into account the actual height of the `#topDiv`

Comment: have a look to the Savado answer, first you get the height of the element then you scroll up that pixel amount

Answer (score 3):

You could get the height of the element by using jQuery's `outerHeight()` and use it to move the div up. The transition can be done with pure CSS. Like this:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#topA").on("click", function(){
    var thisHeight = $("#topDiv").outerHeight();
    $("#topDiv").css({
      'top': '-'+thisHeight+'px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#topDiv {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#fa8072;
  transition: top .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topDiv">This content will disappear when <a id="topA" href="#">this is clicked</a><br/>The text will disappear as the bottom edge of the box moves up.<br/>But the text itself will stay completely static while that happens.</div>
What I would like is for the contents of &lt;div id="topDiv"&gt; to slide up, giving the impression that it is leaving the screen, rather than being hidden.
```

Comment: Very nice - the idea of combining with the CSS transition hadn't occurred to me. Thanks :-)

Comment: @freefaller I'm glad I could help! :) Please mark my comment as the accepted answer, thank you.